# Cannot insert duplicate key. Composite Primary key. ASP.NET Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to create application using Entity Framework.

There's what I want to do (every entity has Id as well):

[image]

I want to use composite primary key in this case (`PatientId + DiagnosisId`).
There's a collection of Diagnoses in Patient model class:

```
public ICollection<Diagnosis> Diagnoses { get; set; }

public class Diagnosis
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public String Type { get; set; }
    public String Complications { get; set; }
    public String Details { get; set; }

    public Int32 DiagnosisId { get; set; }

    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
    public Int32 PatientId { get; set; }
}
```

Also in the database context I defined

```
public DbSet<Diagnosis> Diagnoses { get; set; }
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Diagnosis>().HasKey(x => new { x.DiagnosisId, x.PatientId });
```

in `OnModelCreating` method to create the composite primary key.

In an ASP.NET MVC CRUD controller I create `Diagnosis` and every time `DiagnosisId` is the same = 0. And I can't paste new data to database because it's like duplicate. That's my create post method on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ueXUQ36W) if it could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent key goes first:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Diagnosis>().HasKey(x => new { x.PatientId, x.DiagnosisId });
```

Because you want all the Diagnoses for a particular Patent to be stored together.

And you need to request that the key is generated by the database.  For EF Core its:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Diagnosis>().Property(r => r.DiagnosisId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

for EF6 it's:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Diagnosis>().Property(r => r.DiagnosisId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

Comment: There's absolutely no mention of "Core" anywhere - do you have the syntax for EF6 at hand, too?